# Model-Theory, construction of a model with certain properties

Tags: model-theory

> Let $\mathcal{M}$ be an arbitrarily large infinite model. Let $X$ be a random set.
>
> Show: It exists a model $\mathcal{M}'$, such that
>
> a) $\mathcal{M}'\models\varphi\Leftrightarrow\mathcal{M}\models\varphi$ for every theorem $\varphi$, and
>
> b) it exists an injective function $f: X\to|\mathcal{M}'|$

($|\mathcal{M}'|$ means the carrier set of the model $\mathcal{M}'$)

Hello,

I have a question to this task.
I want to construct a model $\mathcal{M}'$ such that it satisfies the conditions a) and b).
First of all I have a question to the random set $X$.
We have to construct $\mathcal{M}'$ to a given set $X$ which is random, but fixed, right. Therefore $\mathcal{M}'$ is dependend on $X$.
Else it does not make sense, because if $\operatorname{card}(X)>\operatorname{card}(|\mathcal{M}'|)$ you can not always find an injective function $f$.
For example if $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $|\mathcal{M}'|=\mathbb{N}$.

Do you have a hint, how to construct this model?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks as if all you need is that $M'$ is a model of $T$ of cardinality equal or greater than the cardinallty of $X$. This is a consequence of the Upward Lowenheim-Skolem Theorem. We only need $M'$ to be "large" so we can just use compactness.

Comment: Could you give the statement of the Lowenheim-Skolem Theorem? I do not think we proofed it yet.

Comment: Hint: Invent a constant symbol $k_x$ for every element of $X$. Consider the theory $T$ whose axioms are (i) all sentences of our language that are true in $M$ and (ii) the sentences $\lnot(k_x=k_y)$ for every pair $x,y$ of distinct elements of $X$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Expand the language with constants $c_x$, $x\in X$. Apply compactness to  $\operatorname{Th}(\mathcal M)\cup \{c_x\neq c_{x'}\mid x\neq x'\}$.

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought about. To expand $|\mathcal{M}|$ with elements of $X$. But I was unsure, because I thought this could result into theorems $\varphi$, with $\mathcal{M}'\models\varphi$ but $\neg(\mathcal{M}\models\varphi)$. Since $\varphi$ is a theorem, therefor it does not contain free variables, this should not happen. Am I right? To apply compactness I use the compactness theorem?

Comment: If $\mathcal M'$ is a model of the theory of $\mathcal M$, it satisfies its theorems by definition.

Comment: How can I use the compactness theorem to apply compactness to this set? I have to show, that ever finite subset of $\operatorname{Th}(\mathcal{M})\cup\{c_x\neq c_{x'}|x\neq x'\}$ is satisfiable. The finite subsets should be the finite subsets of $\operatorname{Th}(\mathcal{M})$, which are satisfiable.

Comment: Just show that $\mathcal M$ with appropriate interpretations of $c_x$ satisfies a given finite subset.

Comment: So I take a finite subset $\overline{\Sigma}\subseteq\operatorname{Th}(\mathcal{M})\cup\{c_x\neq c_{x'}|x\neq x'\}$ and show that $\mathcal{M}\models\varphi$ for every $\varphi\in\overline{\Sigma}$. If $\varphi\in\operatorname{Th}(\mathcal{M})$ then $\mathcal{M}\models\varphi$ by definition. If $\varphi\in\{c_x\neq c_{x'}|x\neq x'\}$, I have to give a formula where I interprete $c_x$ with constants of $\mathcal{M}$. And show that $\mathcal{M}$ satisfies this formula. Is this correct?

Comment: @MrTopology: you have to choose the interpretations for $c_x$ so that they work for all elements of $\bar\Sigma$. Just make sure that those $c_x$ that show up at all are all distinct and you're done.

Comment: Ok. What do we have now. To get the existence of an injective function $f:X\to\mathcal{M}'$ we just need to construct a model $\mathcal{M}'$ with $card(X)\leq card(|\mathcal{M}'|)$. To do so, we expand the language with constants $c_x$ for every $x\in X$. And now I have to choose the interpretation of $c_x$ in $\mathcal{M}$. So I need an assignment from the variables of $|\mathcal{M}|$ for every $c_x$?

Comment: @MrTopology: No, just an assignment for any finite subset...

Comment: Ok. So let $\overline{\Sigma}$ be a finte subset. The formulas in $\overline{\Sigma}$ are either elements of $\operatorname{Th}(\mathcal{M})$. In that case there is nothing to do. Or $\varphi\in\{c_x\neq c_{x'}|x\neq x'\}$. In that case I choose $v, v'\in|\mathcal{M}|$ with $v\neq v'$, and an assignment $\beta$ which is injective.

Comment: @MrTopology: Almost, but you need to have just one assignment for the whole $\overline\Sigma$, i.e.\ an interpretation of all $c_x$.

Comment: Yes, but that is kinda the point I dont get. $X$ is a random set. But what if the $card(X)<card(|\mathcal{M}|)$? Than this should be impossible. What did I get wrong?

Comment: For each $\overline \Sigma$, only finitely many $c_x$ matter.